# i want to display array in view in yii2

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

i want to display array in view form but i don't know how ?
can any one help me :
my controller code is :

```
$query = new Query;
$query 
    ->select(['Day_Name']) 
    ->from('days')
    ->join( 'INNER JOIN','doctorsworkday','doctorsworkday.Day_id =days.dayid');
$command = $query->createCommand(); 
$dataProvider = $command->queryAll(); 
$dataProvider= array($dataProvider);
return $this->render('view', 
    [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'days'=>$days,
        'doctorsworkday'=>$doctorsworkday,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ])
```

my view code is :

```
<?= 
    DetailView::widget([
        'model' => $dataProvider,
        'attributes' => [
            'Day_Name' 
         ],
     ]) 
?>
```

---

but its shows : (not set)

when i use vat_dump($dataProvider) there is an array .. but i don't know how to show it

[enter Var_Dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuRXI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly you are using a DetailView for displaying multiple results. DetailView is used to display the detail of a single data model as said in the docs. You could use a GridView to display multiple results. GridView accepts a dataProvider not an array so you'll need to turn your array into a dataProvider.

fortunately you can use the class ArrayDataProvider to do just that:

```
$gridViewDataProvider = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
    'allModels' => $dataProvider,
    'sort' => [
        'attributes' => ['Day_Name'],
    ],
    'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10]
]);
```

something like this should work.

Then you pass this $gridViewDataProvider to the gridview like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $gridViewDataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        'name'
    ]
]) ?>
```

Also note that in your controller you wrapped your $dataProvider in an array with this line:

```
$dataProvider= array($dataProvider);
```

You should remove that line and then everything should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: it works fine .. thank you very much .. i appreciate your help :)